# How to run steam games correctly on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: steam

I just wanna post here how to run steam games correctly on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus
First time install steam just open terminal and copy paste these completely step by step:

```sh
mv ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6{,.disable}
mv ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1{,.disable}
cd ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
mv libstdc++.so.6.0.18 libstdc++.so.6.0.18.remove
rm -f libstdc++.so.6
cd ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
mv libstdc++.so.6.0.18 libstdc++.so.6.0.18.remove
rm -f libstdc++.so.6
```

I played Dota 2 and it runs as it should do without fglrx.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If you're answering your own question, you should put the answer part as an actual, separate answer below, so you have a question and an answer, and not a question and an answer in one post. This helps to make answers more easily findable. Thanks :-)

Comment: @JonasCz Can we really ask questions and answer ourselves?

Comment: @Nuwan Yes, you can. [It's encouraged :-)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) There's even an "Answer your own question" checkbox at the bottom of the [ask question page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) to allow you to do so easily.

Comment: @JonasCz Thank you for the news. I am new to this site.

Comment: Isn't the 5th line doing the same as the 1st? That is, making libstdc++.so.6 in the i386-linux-gnu directory unavailable? Looks like someone mashed 2 different peoples suggestions together without thinking them through??

Answer (score 2):

looks like you have typical Steam => AMD errors.

you will need to do this to solve your issues:

1. Right-Click Steam shortcut and click Properties
2. Select the Application tab
3. In the "Command:" path type in this stuff before your steam path. . .

   env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1'

example:

```
env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1' /usr/bin/steam %U
```

it is VERY likely two things will now happen.

1. it will give you an error about 1 or more of the libs saying it cant load them or some such. not all of them are required but that is the general command line. just remove any unnecessary part.
2. steam will now always complain that the steam version is out of date and you need to update. i dont know that there is anything you can actually do about this. it doesnt actually harm anything and steam will still update and function normally.

Comment: Did you read the post?

Comment: sure. steam typically throws up those kind of errors because it doesnt like amd. i have to deal with it all the time having an amd card. which, just saying, steam gives me no problems.

Comment: that's probably not what @edwinksl meant. They meant that the OP encountered a problem and they (the OP) came here to share their solution with us. Your answer is much appreciated, but the OP solved the problem on their own.

Comment: I like David 's solution better.